# MessagePack RPC C# - Server side

Tags: c#, rpc, msgpack, messagepack

I have a problem when trying to consume a server implementation of `MessagePack RPC`. I wrote one implementation for client and one for server based on a Python code provided by my company's client.

The server implementation should be consumed by Python, but as far as I see that won't be a problem.

**Server implementation:**

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultServiceTypeLocator def = new DefaultServiceTypeLocator();
            ServiceTypeLocator ser = def;

            def.AddService(new Methods().GetType());
            var services = ser.FindServices();

            var configuration = new RpcServerConfiguration();

            IPAddress ipAddress = GetIp();
            configuration.BindingEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8089);
            Console.WriteLine(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8089).ToString());
            using (var server = new RpcServer(configuration))
            {
                server.Start();

                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.Write(ex);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
}
[MessagePackRpcServiceContractAttribute]
public class Methods
{
    [MessagePackRpcMethodAttribute]
    public int hello0()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello0");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Client implementation:**

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var configuration = new RpcClientConfiguration();
            IPAddress ipAddress = GetIp();

            using (dynamic proxy = new DynamicRpcProxy(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8089), configuration))
            {
                dynamic res = proxy.hello0();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static IPAddress GetIp()
    {
        string myHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        IPAddress myIP = null;

        for (int i = 0; i <= System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[i].IsIPv6LinkLocal == false)
            {
                if (System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[i].AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    myIP = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[i];
            }
        }
        return myIP;
    }

}
```

My client can't connect to my server, it can't see the methods over there. The error is: "operation does not exist".

Anyone has any clue?

Thank you!!

Comment: You'll have to setup the ServiceTypeLocator using `DefaultServiceTypeLocator`. Add the class that you want to expose using `.AddService()`

Comment: Hi @Caramiriel, Thanks for you comment! I made what you said (I think) and I also added the method and class attributes, but still couldn't do it =(

Comment: @MarianePinheiro please after applying changes to your code, provide an update so we can have a clue what exactly has been changed

Comment: Oh! I am sorry! Tks @DanielGroh it is done.

Comment: @MarianePinheiro where are you using `def`and `services` variable? I believe after adding a service you have to pass this throughout your implementation somehow? The `RpcServer` class is not aware about your service locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after many tries and many help from friends, I finally managed to fix the issue.
First of all you have to download the **Message Pack RPC** solution [here](https://github.com/yfakariya/msgpack-rpc-cli) and create your new project (server or client) inside this solution. In my case the server didn’t work when I created a new solution and referenced the dlls, only inside the whole project. The client worked only referencing the dlls.

Implementation for the **Server Side**:

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args1)
    {
        var config = new RpcServerConfiguration();

        config.BindingEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8089);

        config.PreferIPv4 = true;

        config.IsDebugMode = true;
 //UseFullMethodName is a property that if it is false allows you in the CLIENT to call the         methods only by it's name, check example further.
        config.UseFullMethodName = false;

        var defaultServiceTypeLocator = new DefaultServiceTypeLocator();

        //Methods is the class I created with all the methods to be called.
        defaultServiceTypeLocator.AddService(typeof(Methods));

        config.ServiceTypeLocatorProvider = conf => defaultServiceTypeLocator;

        using (var server = new RpcServer(config))
        {
            server.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
}

[MessagePackRpcServiceContract] //Define the contract to be used   
public class Methods 
{
    [MessagePackRpcMethod] //Define the methods that are going to be exposed
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
    [MessagePackRpcMethod]
    public string HelloParam(string i)
    {
        return "Hello " + i;
    }
 }
```

Implementation for the **Client Side**:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var target = CreateClient())
        {

            //var result1 = target.Call("Hello:Methods:0", null); /*if in the server the property UseFullMethodName is true, or not defined as false (default is true) you have to call the method on the server using *methodname:class:version**/
            var result2 = target.Call("Hello", null); //Parameter is null
            var result3 = target.Call("HelloParam", “Mariane”);//Method with parameter
         }

    }

    public static RpcClient CreateClient()
    {
        return new RpcClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8089), new RpcClientConfiguration() { PreferIPv4 = true });
    }
```

I hope this is clear and help you guys to fix it. Don’t forget to set the methods as public on the server. Thanks to [https://github.com/yfakariya /msgpack-rpc-cli/issues/6](https://github.com/yfakariya%20/msgpack-rpc-cli/issues/6) that answered my question. Really special thanks to @DanielGroh that spent some time with me trying to fix it and Gilmar Pereira which has no profile here but is a great developer and helped me a lot (https:// www. facebook .com/ gilmarps?fref=ts).